# Out of memory exception with bitmaps

Tags: android, bitmap, surfaceview, out-of-memory, bitmapfactory

i have problem in my app. When switching in landspace mode, the setContentView() method is called to show a piano keyboard. The piano keyboard class extends Surfaceview for better performance showing pressed keys. This SurfaceView class is added as child to my landscape layout:

```
RelativeLayout rootLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
relativeLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.relativeLayoutLowerBar);
rootLayout.addView(keyboardSurfaceView, relativeLayoutParams);
```

In my keyboardSurfaceView class im loading bitmaps in an Bitmap array with the BitmapFactory.decodeResource() method and holding the bitmaps till the app is destroyed. This works great. When im swiching in portrait mode, i change layout with setContentView() and remove the keyboardSurfaceView :

```
if(keyboardSurfaceView != null && keyboardSurfaceView.getParent() != null)
        ((ViewGroup) keyboardSurfaceView.getParent()).removeView(keyboardSurfaceView);
```

The Bitmaps are loaded once. First time when switched in landscape mode. I encountered an out of memory error, when swichtin up to 10-20  times from protrait in landscape an so forth. When i update the heap in ddms view, i can see, that every time, when i switch from protrait view in landscape view, the heap size is growing up to ca. 20mb and then the app crashes. I dont know why this is happening all the time. The bitmaps are just loaded once and not every time. 
I also tried `bitmap.recycle(); bitmap = null`without success. Also tried to cache bitmaps with the LRUCache class as described in Google best practices. I also searched stackoverflow for a proper solution for my problem. Can still not fix this. I handle portrait/ landscape changes by myself (have onConfigurationChanged() method overriden). Putting all images in drawable-xhdpi helped a little. The heap size is growing as before, when changing orientation, but is still growing. Any help would be appreciated...

Exception:

```
 02-13 22:44:09.419: E/dalvikvm-heap(935): 11448-byte external allocation too large for this process.
02-13 22:44:09.419: E/dalvikvm(935): Out of memory: Heap Size=16391KB, Allocated=13895KB, Bitmap Size=16394KB, Limit=32768KB
02-13 22:44:09.419: E/dalvikvm(935): Trim info: Footprint=16391KB, Allowed Footprint=16391KB, Trimmed=432KB
02-13 22:44:09.419: E/GraphicsJNI(935): VM won't let us allocate 11448 bytes
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's Android document of how to handle bitmap efficiently

> http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: i have already read that, but without success. Problem is the growing heap even though bitmaps are already in memory

Comment: If so, can you post more code as you code may contains mistake some where else.

Answer (score 0):

ok first time when surfaceCreated is called in my surfaceView class, i call this method, and this method is called only once and not every time i show the surfaceView on screen:

```
bitmapKeyboard = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.keyboard); 

bitmapGlowImages[0] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.keycdown); 
bitmapGlowImages[1] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.blackkeydown);
bitmapGlowImages[2] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.keyddown);
bitmapGlowImages[3] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.blackkeydown);
bitmapGlowImages[4] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.keyedown);
bitmapGlowImages[5] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.keycdown); 
bitmapGlowImages[6] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.blackkeydown);
bitmapGlowImages[7] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.keyddown);
bitmapGlowImages[8] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.blackkeydown);
bitmapGlowImages[9] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.keyddown);
bitmapGlowImages[10] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.blackkeydown);
bitmapGlowImages[11] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.keyedown);
```

in this class in also run a seperate thread to draw pressed keys: with `canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, destRect, null)`. Finally, when onDestroy is called, my method recycleBitmaps() is called

```
public void recycleBitmaps() {
        if(bitmapKeyboard != null) {
            bitmapKeyboard.recycle();
            bitmapKeyboard = null;
            for(int i = 0; i < bitmapGlowImages.length; i++) {
                bitmapGlowImages[i].recycle();
                bitmapGlowImages[i] = null;
            }
            System.gc();
        }
}
```

That's it. And every time in landscape, i add my surfaceView to my parent View in my landscape layout and in portrait i remove it again, and load my portrait layout. I make this in `onConfigurationChanged()`, because i handle orientation changes by myself, so the app is not destroyed and created every time when you change the device orientation.

Comment: ok, its possible that is not crashing the app now. I rotated the devics about 20-30 times. after 6-7 rotations its still allocating more storage on the heap (but now, only 300-400kb). When heap size was reached, it crashed before, and now its only increasing the heap size. I copied my png files in all drawable folders (mdpi, ldpi, xhdpi, hdpi). But problem exists anyway... I think its related to the picture scaling ldpi, hdpi etc.